# PHPFOX : Which function finally generate password in https://github.com/Criotin/phpfox/blob/master/PF.Src/Core/Hash.php

Tags: phpfox

Can anyone tell me which function finally we should call to generate encrypted password from bellow link?

**https://github.com/Criotin/phpfox/blob/master/PF.Src/Core/Hash.php**

For example my password is " gauravjain "

how and which function i should use to finally generate encrypted password to save in dataase? I want to migrate old custom users to phpfox v4

can anyone give example code here using my example passowrd

Answer (score 0):

```
$password = (new Core\Hash())->make($aVals['password']);
```

I hope this is the code you need.

Comment: it means if pwd is " gauravjain " thenit will covert in phpfox v4 password

Comment: this error come Fatal error: Class 'Core\Core\Hash' not found in

Comment: You might do something wrong. See this line of code: https://github.com/Criotin/phpfox/blob/master/PF.Base/module/user/include/service/process.class.php#L379